# Triggering email via AMPscript, two rows in data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am testing the code for a potential preference centre. I am passing the email address and subscriber key from an email and I am saving the data into a triggered send data extension which then sends an email with the confirmation of the selections.

All of this works; the only part of the code where I have issues with is the fact that in my triggered send data extension I see my record being added twice. Please see print screen attached & my code.

Any guidance how to correct this is appreciated:

```
%%[
var @key,@email,@ts, @tsDef, @ts_sub, @ts_attr, @tsctr, @ts_subkey, @ts_statusCode, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode
set @key=QueryParameter("key")
set @email=QueryParameter("email")


if RequestParameter("submitted") == true then

  InsertData(
        "TriggeredSendDataBOZIPAGESSSSSSS",
        "SubscriberKey", RequestParameter("SubscriberKey"),
        "EmailAddress", RequestParameter("email"),
        "Preference1", RequestParameter("Preference1"),
        "Preference2", RequestParameter("Preference2"),
        "Newsletter", RequestParameter("Newsletter"),
        "Travel", RequestParameter("Travel")
       )
SET @ts = CreateObject("TriggeredSend")
SET @tsDef = CreateObject("TriggeredSendDefinition")
SET @ts_subkey=QueryParameter("key")
SetObjectProperty(@tsDef, "CustomerKey", "TRIGGEREDSENDSSSS")
SetObjectProperty(@ts, "TriggeredSendDefinition", @tsDef)
SET @ts_sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "EmailAddress", QueryParameter("email"))
IF NOT EMPTY(@ts_subkey) THEN
    SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", @ts_subkey)
ELSE
    SetObjectProperty(@ts_sub, "SubscriberKey", QueryParameter("email"))
ENDIF
AddObjectArrayItem(@ts, "Subscribers", @ts_sub)
SET @ts_statusCode = InvokeCreate(@ts, @ts_statusMsg, @errorCode)

IF @ts_statusCode != "OK" THEN
    RaiseError(@ts_statusMsg, 0, @ts_statusCode, @errorCode)
ENDIF


endif

]%%

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
      %%[ if RequestParameter("submitted") == true then ]%%
         <p>Thank you for submitting your details.</p>
      %%[ else ]%%
      <h2>Hello %%=v(@key)=%%</h2>

      <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
         <label>Newsletter</label>
         <input type="radio" name="Newsletter" checked><br>
         <label>Travel</label>
         <input type="radio" name="Travel" checked><br>
         <label>SubscriberKey</label>
         <input type="text" name="SubscriberKey" value="%%=v(@key)=%%"><br>
         <label>Email</label>
         <input type="text" name="email"  value="%%=v(@email)=%%"><br>
         <label>Preference 1</label>
         <input type="text" name="Preference1"><br>
         <label>Preference 2</label>
         <input type="text" name="Preference2"><br>
         <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true" />
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">

      </form>
      %%[ endif ]%%
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Triggering an email will automatically add a row to the Data Extension configured in the Triggered Send Definition.  No need to add a row manually.

Comment: Right at @Giulietta, so like Adam said, you are getting two rows because the system is adding the row once, and your manual entry is adding it a second time.

Comment: Thank you @Adam Spriggs &garek007. I was able to modify the script and now it works as it should